# Trying to get data from storage but it returns empty array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have data stored using custom keys. I want to return all data that starts with the id `KEY-` so I loop over all the data and storage and push the ones that match into an array. I can see that the data is being pushed into `data[]`
but when I call `getData()` in my component it returns an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

storage.ts

```
getData(): any {
  this.storage.ready().then(() =>
  {
    let data = [];
    this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) =>
    {
      if (value.id.startsWith("KEY-")) {
        data.push(value);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    return data;
  });
}
```

component.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.data = this.storage.geData(); 
}
```

I've also tried this way

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.storage.getData().then(data => console.log(data));
 }
```

Comment: It might be because the `return` statement is in the wrong place.   I would think you need to move it down a line so it's just outside the closing function bracket.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't immediately use promise result or return data from it. What you can do is only return a promise, then you can use it anywhere as promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just return a promise from your function then try to resolve `data` with this promise.

```
getData(): any {
  return this.storage.ready().then(() =>
  {
    let data = [];
    this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) =>
    {
      if (value.id.startsWith("KEY-")) {
        data.push(value);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    return data;
  });
}
```